# I can't change the color of the background with a click button

Tags: android

I'm trying to change the color of the background by clicking button. For example: clicking “Y” should make it yellow, “G” green, and so on, but clicking the buttons doesn’t change anything. I’ve only implemented two buttons, but they didn’t work. Can anybody tell me where I’m going wrong?

This my activity:

```java
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    // Declare UI elements
    private Button firstButton;
    private Button secondButton;
    private ImageView changeBackground;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); // Our only layout for this app is main.xml

        // Initialize the UI components
        changeBackground = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backGround);
        firstButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        // When we creating a button and if we expect that to use for event handling we have to set the listener
        firstButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        secondButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        secondButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    // Have to implement with the OnClickListner
    // onClick is called when a view has been clicked.
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { // Parameter v stands for the view that was clicked.  

        if(v.getId() == R.id.button1){
            // setText() sets the string value of the TextView
            changeBackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

        }else if(v.getId() == R.id.button2){
            changeBackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        }


    }
}
```

and my XML:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#CCEEFF"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

     <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/backGround"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

       />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/backGround"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:text="@string/white" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="@string/black" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:text="@string/red" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
        android:text="@string/yellow" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
        android:text="@string/green"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: so you want change the background of `imageview`? what is the source of that? I think your code is right.But you must set source for your image to test that

Comment: you can test your code with `firstButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);`

Comment: I just want to change the background to color RED, and if I press antoher button to another color and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may not be right, but your ImageView won't appear at all if you do not put some content in it:

```
<ImageView

    android:id="@+id/backGround"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

   />
```

Both width and height are set to wrap its contents, which it doesn't have.

Try using this:

```
<ImageView

    android:id="@+id/backGround"
    android:layout_width="200px"
    android:layout_height="200px"

   />
```

EDIT:

Here's how you would do it. Use a switch instead of ifs and elses, that will get too messy.

```
package com.example.imageview;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

        // Declare UI elements
        private Button firstButton;
        private Button secondButton, thirdButton, fourthButton, fifthButton;
        private ImageView changeBackground;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // Our only layout for this app is main.xml

            // Initialize the UI components
            changeBackground = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backGround);
            firstButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            // When we creating a button and if we expect that to use for event handling we have to set the listener
            firstButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            secondButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            secondButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            thirdButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
            thirdButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            fourthButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
            fourthButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            fifthButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
            fifthButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        // Have to implement with the OnClickListner
        // onClick is called when a view has been clicked.
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { // Parameter v stands for the view that was clicked.  

            switch(v.getId()) {

            case R.id.button1:
                changeBackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                changeBackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                changeBackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                break;
            case R.id.button4:
                changeBackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                break;
            case R.id.button5:
                changeBackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

And don't forget to fix your xml layout, otherwise you wont see anything.

1) in your xml file add an id to your layout.

```
android:id="@+id/myLayout"
```

2) Declare your layout object in your Activity class:

```
RelativeLayout myLayout;
```

3) Hook up your layout in the onCreate() method of your Activity.

```
myLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
```

4) In the onClick method change changeBackGround to myLayout (you want to set the back ground color for this object, all instances, obviously.) For example:

```
myLayout.setBackGroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: but that's not the problem... :/

Comment: Set your ImageView's width and height to some value, like 200px. I'll edit the code above for you. If your ImageView has no source of content and you tell it to wrap its content, than it will wrap nothing, i.e. you won't see it at runtime apppearing in your layout.

Comment: But I don't want to change the background of Text, I want to change the background totally... the color text it's not important... :/

Comment: I am not talking about the TextView, but the **ImageView**.

Comment: Well if you want to change the background color of the whole layout, why are you manipulating the ImageView in your OnClick method? In this case you need to call the setBackGroundColor on your layout object.

Comment: Now works :) and if I want to change the whole "wallpaper" instead of the ImageView? What do I have to change?

Comment: I assume that by "wallpaper" you mean the layout object. I'll add some code to my comment in a minute.